# How to hide #id object

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using lightbox (it is basically fancybox), and I'm using the inline feature (so link is clicked and some text pops up).

I am defining the text as the following:

```
<p id="wald" style="width:500px; border:2px solid #ececec; padding:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
<strong>id="loremipsum"</strong> Nullam varius congue fringilla. Curabitur auctor dapibus molestie. Cras malesuada vestibulum lectus, vel ullamcorper nibh tempus lobortis. Donec ipsum magna, malesuada et fringilla eget, placerat ut arcu. Donec aliquet, mauris ut pellentesque tincidunt, massa dolor tempor urna, ac interdum massa nisl id tellus. Maecenas eu nunc varius lorem porttitor faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ullamcorper vehicula pretium. In aliquam adipiscing mi, rhoncus eleifend felis auctor eu. Aenean et mi vitae ante ultricies pulvinar a vel neque.
</p>
```

but the problem is that the text shows up on the bottom of the page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but do you just want to add `display:none` to the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to hide a object using CSS you write

```
.[class of element] {display:none; }

#[id of element]  {display:none;}
```

you can also use `{visibility:hidden}`

using jQuery you can do this with

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //this is used it we want to access multiple style add extra with comma sperated values. 
  $("#[id of element]").css({display:none});
  $(".[class of element]").css({display:none});
```

or you can also try

```
  //this is used it we want to access only one style 
  $("#[id of element]").css('display','none');
  $(".[class of element]").css('display','none');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
//add display:none, so that its hidden and opens in fancybox when clicked if you have valid code
<p id="wald" style="width:500px; border:2px solid #ececec; padding:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto; display:none;">
//OR
<div style="display:none;">
<p id="wald" style="width:500px; border:2px solid #ececec; padding:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :
in your html:

```
    <a href="#" id="show_dialog">click this to show dialog</a>

    <p id="wald" style="width:500px; border:2px solid #ececec; padding:10px; margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
<strong>id="loremipsum"</strong> Nullam varius congue fringilla. Curabitur auctor dapibus molestie. Cras malesuada vestibulum lectus, vel ullamcorper nibh tempus lobortis. Donec ipsum magna, malesuada et fringilla eget, placerat ut arcu. Donec aliquet, mauris ut pellentesque tincidunt, massa dolor tempor urna, ac interdum massa nisl id tellus. Maecenas eu nunc varius lorem porttitor faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ullamcorper vehicula pretium. In aliquam adipiscing mi, rhoncus eleifend felis auctor eu. Aenean et mi vitae ante ultricies pulvinar a vel neque.
</p>
```

then type this in your .js code. (you need [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to do this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#wald').hide();
     $('#show_dialog').click(function(){
            $('#wald').show();

     });
});
```